# NoReverseMatch with keyword arguments not found when the keyword arguments match

Tags: django

I'm getting the error:

> Reverse for 'search_blog' with keyword arguments '{'search_terms': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog/search/(?P[^/]+)/$']

So, my arguments match and yet I'm getting a NoReverseMatch...

I've tried removing the `<str:search_terms>` pattern from the 'search_blog' path and excluded the kwargs parameter from my reverse call, and that worked. So, the problem must lie solely in the url pattern. I tried renaming the pattern to 'terms' but got the same error:

> Reverse for 'search_blog' with keyword arguments '{'terms': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog/search/(?P[^/]+)/$']

Here are the relevant snippets:

*urls.py*

```
path('search/', views.nav_search_input, name='nav_search_input'),
path('search/<str:search_terms>/', views.search_blog, name='search_blog'),
```

*views.py*

```
def nav_search_input(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SearchBlog(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('search_blog', kwargs={'search_terms': form.cleaned_data['search_terms']}))

    else:
        form = SearchBlog()

    context = {
        'form': form
    }

    return render(request, 'index.html', context)


def search_blog(request, search_terms=''):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    form = SearchBlog()

    if form.is_valid():
        posts = Post.objects.all().filter(title__contains=search_terms)

    context = {
        'form': form,
        'posts': posts
    }

    return render(request, 'blog/search_blog.html', context)
```

and the *forms.py* in case you need it

```
class SearchBlog(forms.Form):
    search_terms = forms.CharField(required=False)

    def clean_search_terms(self):
        search_terms = self.cleaned_data['search_terms']
        return search_terms
```

The nav_search_input view lets me use a form in the base.html so that I can search the site from any page in the nav. The form input data should then go through nav_search_input to the search_blog view where the results are displayed. However I just get the error when I search from the nav form.

Comment: `search_terms` seems to be required for your form, remove `required=False`

Comment: @IainShelvington Thanks, I meant for the form to accept no search terms which would return a results page with everything. But your comment made me look into the base template (which I haven't even posted a snippet from) and realize that I haven't given my input the name of "search_terms." Also, my `search_blog` view didn't even pass the `search_terms` argument to the `SearchBlog` call... What a novice I am.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Roman to Roman: please check your base template. Check every file that has to do with the `search_blog` form. The error may show up somewhere you don't expect (clearly from your not posting a snippet from the template).

Add a name to the character field matching the form input field variable name: `<input type="search" name="search_terms">`. (I didn't want to delete this question so I answered it myself, I wish I could close this question.)